# Mismatched file sort capability

Tags: files

Previously, using Windows, I developed a large file structure.  Now that I've changed to Linux (Elementary OS), I'm experiencing a discrepancy in sorting capability.  To wit:

When I look at my file structure in LibreOffice (or Windows), exclamation points sort ahead of alphanumeric characters.  But when I look at the file structure using the Files application, the exclamation points are ignored by the system.

I don't want to go through all my files and delete the exclamation points, because there are thousands of them and it would be a huge nuisance.

How can I make my files sort the same way, with exclamation points coming before letters and numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about the exclamation points, but files which start with a dot `.` are considered as Hidden Files, and if you want to see them into the files application, you have to enable **Show hidden files** by a right click into an empty space in the Files application window and setting on the corresponding checkbox in the context menu.

Comment: My files of concern aren't hidden, they're just in the incorrect order.  Does anyone else have any ideas?